# TFS Build Deploy

Tags: tfs, msdeploy

Hi I am using TFS and want do deploy two web applications after build to a test server.
After the deployment I want to call a web page at one of the web applications to trigger some work like, delete all data and insert test data.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [TFSDeployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/).  If you are comfortable with Powershell, you can write a deployment script that does whatever you want, and TFSDeployer will execute it when it detects changes to the build quality (i.e. you set build quality to "deploy to test" for example and it will run the script to deploy to the test environment).  There's more information on the site, and this is what I use almost always for deployments.

Answer (score 1):

You can MS Deploy to deploy your applications to the test environments: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/12/Auto-deployment-of-my-web-application-with-Team-Build-2010-to-add-Interactive-Testing.aspx.

To call a web application, you can either create a codedui that you run as part of your testing, or you add an activity to your build template that calls the web site: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/?tag=/build+2010+customization

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DeployToAzure](http://deploytoazure.codeplex.com). It publishes specified cloud project to Azure as a part of your TFS build workflow. Publishing is executed after solution is built and unit tested are passed. You can include some steps (like call web page) after that.

And you don't need any Powershell programming for that.

Check here for additional information: [Deploying Azure Project from TFS 2010 Build Server](http://www.koltovich.com/blog/DeployingAzureProjectFromTFS2010BuildServer.aspx)